# C++ in G++ - Segmentation Fault when not using pointers

Tags: c++, g++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to use G++ to compile some C++ code. It seems to work fine in other compilers, but for whatever reason, G++ won't produce working output.

**Disclosure:** This is part of a homework assignment, but I feel like it's more of a compiler issue, since it works in other compilers.

Here's the snippet that's wreaking havoc:

```
set<int> t1, t2;
```

It's strange because the following code works just fine:

```
set<int> *t1 = new set<int>();
set<int> *t2 = new set<int>();
```

Granted, I have to use `->` instead of `.`, but that's expected. The first snippet produces a segmentation fault at runtime. The second does intuitively what I'd expect it to.

Anyhow, behind the scenes, the `.cpp` for `set` has this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
set<T>::set() : bag<T>() {}

template <class T>
set<T>::set(const set<T>& b) : bag<T>(b) {}
```

The `.h` looks like this:

```
#include "bag.h"

template <class T>
class set : public bag<T>
{ 
    public:
        set( );
        set(const set &b);

// ...

};
#include "set.cpp"
```

And last but not least, the `bag.cpp` and `bag.h` files looks like this:

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
bag<T>::bag() {
    head = NULL;
}

template <class T>
bag<T>::bag(const bag<T>& b) {

    // ...

}
```

and `bag.h`:

```
template <class T>
class bag
{ 
    public:
        bag( );
        bag(const bag &b);

    // ...
};
#include "bag.cpp"
```

Again, I feel like G++ just hates me, but then again I could be doing something dumb. Just a simple nudge in the right direction would be great.

Comment: `using namespace std` combined with naming your class the same thing as a standard library name (`set`) can only end in tears.

Comment: What, exactly, do the destructors of `set` and `bag` do?  (When you create an object on the stack as in the first code snippet, the object is destroyed at the end of its enclosing scope block.  When you create an object dynamically using `new` as in the second code snippet, the object is destroyed when you `delete` it.  If you never `delete` it, the destructor will never be called; I'd guess that something in the destructor is likely the cause of your problem `</psychic-debugging>`).

Comment: @James: I renamed the class to `discreet_set`. No effect. As for the destructor, it iterates a linked list and deletes the value of each node. Nothing fancy, but I'll tinker and let you know. Thanks so far!

Comment: Unless your set demonstrates prudence and is judicious in its conduct and speech, you might want to name it `discrete_set`.  :-)  [Seriously, though, this demonstrates one really good reason not to use using directives at file scope.  They are nothing but trouble.  In the long run it is far easier just to qualify names that are in namespaces.]

Comment: Haha, my bad. Actually named it `discrete_set`, but that's not what my fingers wanted to type. It's a little late here ;D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a general hint that will make your life a million times easier.

Compile this program with the "-g" and "-Wall" flags:

```
gcc -g -Wall foo.cpp
```

The "-g" adds debugging information.  The "-Wall" spits out additional warnings when compiling.  Then use the debugger:

```
gdb ./a.out
```

Hit **run** to start your program.  Use **bt** to dump your call stack once your code 
crashes.  You can then see exactly where the crash is happening in your code.

While you're at it, google "gdb tutorial".  Spending an hour or two learning how to use gdb properly will pay itself back, with interest.  I promise you.

Comment: Wow was I off. And also, **holy crap**. Best thing ever. `gdb` is my new favorite "toy". Much appreciated!